# Splitting latlong into lat and long

Tags: python, regex, formatting, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to remove the square brackets from a list of latlongs called ***latlng***, which is held in a dataframe (***df***) in the format as per example below:

```
        latlng
[-1.4253128, 52.9015902]
```

I've got this but it returns NaN:

```
df['latitude'] = df['latlng'].str.replace('[','')
```

and produces this warning:

```
<ipython-input-59-34b588ef7f4b>:1: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will*not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
  df['latitude'] = df['latlng'].str.replace('[','')
```

It seems that if I write the file to a csv and then use that file, the above works. But ideally, I want it all in once script.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write `df['latitude'] = str(df['latlng']).replace('[','')`.

Yet, this only removes the opening bracket and will not return long or lat alone.

You might want to use regex to split the string, something on the lines such as

```
import re

splitted = re.match("\[(-?\d+\.\d+),\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)\]", "[-1.4253128, 52.9015902]")
print(splitted[1])
print(splitted[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indices:

```py
df['latitude'] = df['latlng'].str[0]
df['longitude'] = df['latlng'].str[1]
```

Even if they are objects, `str[]` accessor allows access to their values.